# Pandas and dataframe: How to transform a ordinal variable in a binary variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of my dataframe `df = pd.read_csv('somedata')` namely df['rank'] which is an ordinal variable. I want to create a binary column where df['rkGood'] is equal to 1 when df['rank'] ranges from 20 to 40, and 0 otherwise.

I am trying something like this, but it is not working:

```
df['rkGood']= 1 if (df['rank']>20 & df['rank']<=40) else 0
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First initialize your column to zeros, then use `loc` as follows:

```
df['rkGood'] = 0
df.loc[(df['rank'] > 20) & (df['rank'] <= 40), 'rkGood'] = 1
```

Or...

```
df['rkGood'] = 0
df.loc[df.rank.between(20, 40, inclusive=True), 'rkGood'] = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['rkGood'] = np.where((df['rank'] > 20) & (df['rank'] <= 40),  1, 0)
```